# PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 7, number of columns: 6 - Postgres beginner

Tags: java, postgresql

This is a database that I'm building to use with a sample website.

I'm using play 1.3

Here's the structure:

```
@Entity
public class BlogUser extends BlogModel {

    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    public Long id;

    public String firstName;

    public String lastName;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    public String username;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    public String password;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    public String email;

    public BlogUser(String fName, String lName, String uName, String pWord, String email1) {
        firstName = fName;
        lastName = lName;
        username = uName;
        password = pWord;
        email = email1;
    }
}
```

This is the command from the controller

```
public static void registerSubmit(String firstName, String lastName, String username, String password, String email) throws FileNotFoundException {

    BlogUser user = new BlogUser(firstName, lastName, username, password, email);

    //persists the entity in the database
    try {
        user.save();
    }
    catch (PersistenceException e) {
        File file = new File("testsalotofthem.txt");
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(file);
        e.printStackTrace(ps);
    }
}
```

Some of the things have attributes done manually and some don't, that's just me trying to learn all the ways things can be set (what's allowed, what you have to do manually, what can be handled either way).

I'm trying to persist a user in the database. It has all the data, but for some reason it says I'm trying to use 7 columns instead of 6.

The data is coming in from a website and that command is where the information is coming in for the user.

Any tips to fix this would help a lot as I'm stumped.

Here's the stack trace:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not insert: [models.BlogUser]
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1387)
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1310)
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1316)
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:999)
at play.db.jpa.JPABase._save(JPABase.java:45)
at play.db.jpa.GenericModel.save(GenericModel.java:232)
at controllers.Application.registerSubmit(Application.java:50)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeWithContinuation(ActionInvoker.java:524)
at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:475)
at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:451)
at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:446)
at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:160)
at play.server.PlayHandler$NettyInvocation.execute(PlayHandler.java:267)
at play.Invoker$Invocation$1.apply(Invoker.java:290)
at play.Invoker$Invocation$1.apply(Invoker.java:287)
at play.db.jpa.JPA.withTransaction(JPA.java:258)
at play.db.jpa.JPA.withinFilter(JPA.java:217)
at play.db.jpa.JPAPlugin$TransactionalFilter.withinFilter(JPAPlugin.java:299)
at play.Invoker$Invocation.withinFilter(Invoker.java:271)
at play.Invoker$Invocation.run(Invoker.java:287)
at play.server.PlayHandler$NettyInvocation.run(PlayHandler.java:245)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not insert: [models.BlogUser]
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:135)
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3087)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3509)
at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:88)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:377)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:369)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:286)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:339)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:52)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1234)
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:996)
... 28 more

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 7, number of columns: 6.
at org.postgresql.core.v3.SimpleParameterList.bind(SimpleParameterList.java:53)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.SimpleParameterList.setLiteralParameter(SimpleParameterList.java:114)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.bindLiteral(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:2172)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.setLong(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:1227)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.setLong(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:170)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BigIntTypeDescriptor$1.doBind(BigIntTypeDescriptor.java:57)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:93)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:280)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:275)
at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.nullSafeSet(ComponentType.java:358)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrateId(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2823)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2792)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3064)
... 37 more
```

Edit: Added save() method from the play jpa GenericModel.java

```
public <T extends JPABase> T save() {
    _save();
    return (T) this;
}
```

Edit2: Added BlogUser Table

```
            Table "public.bloguser"
  Column   |          Type          | Modifiers 
-----------+------------------------+-----------
 id        | bigint                 | not null
 email     | character varying(255) | not null
 firstname | character varying(255) | 
 lastname  | character varying(255) | 
 password  | character varying(255) | not null
 username  | character varying(255) | not null
Indexes:
    "bloguser_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

Comment: Can you show the code for save() method?

Comment: Sure, I'll add it as an edit.

Comment: I suggest you set Hibernate parameter show_sql=true to see the generated SQL

Comment: I added that, but it isn't showing any SQL, I am sure I added that to the right place.

Comment: please show the definition of the `BlogUser ` table - it may not have all the columns you think it does

Comment: I'll add the definition that I have in the db

Comment: I don't know if that's what you were asking for. I'm new at this, I'm using hibernate as well.

Answer (score 9):

This is a bit old, but I just ran into the same error on an older app that was built on Play 1.x where I was upgrading some of the libraries, so I figured this might help someone else out. One of the following is likely to fix the error:

1. Missing column - An obvious one, but probably the most likely reason for the error. Adding jpa.default.ddl=update to your application.conf file while in dev mode will typically fix this for you.
2. Discriminator Column - (this is where my problem was) If you upgraded hibernate then you probably need to add @Column(insertable = false, updatable = false) annotation to the discriminator field in your superclass. The newer versions of JPA don't have the same @Column defaults as the older versions (believe its 2.1 where they change this).